# How to property handle API Audits

Tags: c#

At the moment I have a method, `GetUsers`, I wrote some pseudoCode below. My insert and update code are transactional operations but I am having issues now if GetUsers if called a ton of time. Seems to be a deadlock of some sort. The reason I set insert/update code to be transactional is because when an error is thrown, all the db work is rolled back, which I need to prevent. All the audits need to commit but anything else can rollback.

```
public Task GetUsers()
{
    var audit = auditService.InsertAudit();

    try {
        ... code for getting users...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         auditService.UpdateAudit(audit);
         throw new Error("Get Users Failed")
    }
}
```

AuditService

```
public async Task<Audit> InsertAudit()
{
     using (transactional unit of work)
     {
           ....
     }
}
```

Wonder if I can get any tips on how to property inserting records into database that commits and be able to throw an error **safely**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a thread-safe object collection to manage the inserts. I would use a blocking collection for this so that the insertions can be added to the collection and then run one after the other.

So you would call GetUsers() and then add the result to a blocking collection. Once it is populated, you can run a task to consume each of the collection items and perform the insertion. Each insertion will not take place until the previous is insertion complete.

Examples of this can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8_)

In terms of throwing exceptions safely, you can catch and throw the exception on each insert or aggregate them and throw one exception for all inserts performed.